# LibGDX Draw multiple actors in one table cell scroll pane

Tags: fonts, libgdx, textures, scrollpane

I currently have a scroll pane fully functional like so:

[image: Picture of Level Screen]

Only the blue boxes in the middle are implemented with a scroll pane, so only the middle section of the screen scrolls. The scroll pane is implemented like so:

```
    final Table scrollTable = new Table();
    for (int j = 0; j < 60; j+=3) {
        for (int i = j; i < j+3; i++) {
            scrollTable.add(items.getValueAt(i).getImage()).center().padRight(80).size(200, 300).padBottom(70);
        }
        scrollTable.row();
    }

    final ScrollPane scroller = new ScrollPane(scrollTable);
    scroller.setScrollingDisabled(true, false);
    final Table table = new Table();
    table.setBounds(0, 300, GameWorld.gameWidth, GameWorld.gameHeight - 600);

    table.add(scroller);

    GameScreen.stage.addActor(table);
```

The issue I have is each box is drawn in a cell (I believe) in the table and what I need to do is draw using a font (possibly a texture too) the number of the level on top of the box like so:

[image: Level box with font draw on top]

The problem is I can't simply draw on top of the screen because the font will be static whilst the user scrolls down the table, so I need to add the font into the table so it scrolls with the table, but every time I try to add it it can only be added as a separate cell, and not on top of an already drawn cell.

Is there a way of drawing a cell on top of another cell so I can draw my font in one cell and put it over my level box texture? Or is there a better solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, you can add the labels on a new row below the texture and use `table.add(texture).padTop(-200)` to bring it up over the first row. I drew 3 rows, the first being the boxes, the second being the level number and the third being the number of stars achieved in that level and used `.padTop()` to bring the last 2 rows up over the first row to make it look like it's all one row.

Final result:

[image: Completed level UI]

The code (roughly) is below:

```
for (int j = 0; j < LevelFiles.maxLvl; j += 3) {

        //Level Boxes
        for (int i = j; i < j + 3; i++) {
            if(i == j)scrollTable.add(levelBoxes.getValueAt(i).getImage()).center().size(200, 300).padBottom(70);
            if(i == j+1)scrollTable.add(levelBoxes.getValueAt(i).getImage()).center().size(200, 300).pad(0, 100, 0, 100).padBottom(70);
            if(i == j+2)scrollTable.add(levelBoxes.getValueAt(i).getImage()).center().size(200, 300).padBottom(70);
        }
        scrollTable.row();

        //Fonts
        for (int i = j; i < j + 3; i++) {
            scrollTable.add(new Label(i+1 + "", l)).padTop(-450);
        }
        scrollTable.row();

        //Stars
        for (int i = j; i < j + 3; i++) {
            if((i+1) <= LevelFiles.maxLvl){
                scrollTable.add(threeStars[i]).prefHeight(100).prefWidth(262).padRight(0).padTop(-200);
            }
        }
        scrollTable.row();

}
```